# PHP User/Admin Login using Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, authentication

The below code is used on my admin login page, which redirects to admin only page(s) upon a successful login. Via the database values, I need only users with an admin value of 1 to be granted access, while users with an admin value of 0 get prompted an error message similar to the "invalid username or password". Please signify placement of additional code.

Also, please keep in mind that I take code and patch together as best I can to work for me, so I'm not very fluent in php. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
DATABASE
ID    Username    Password    Admin
1     John        ••••••      0
2     Aaron       ••••••      1
```

---

```
<?php 

    require("connect.php");

    // Re-display the username if they fail to enter correct password. 
    $submitted_username = ''; 

    // Determine whether the login form has been submitted 
    // If it has, run the login code, otherwise display form 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // Retrieve the users info from the database using username 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                admin
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username
        ";

        // The parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        );      

        try 
        { 
            // Execute query against database 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 


        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $login_ok = false; 

        // Retrieve user data from database.  If $row is false, username in not registered
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 
            // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database, 
            // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password 
            // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database. 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

            if($check_password === $row['password']) 
            { 
                // If they do, then we flip this to true 
                $login_ok = true; 
            }           
        } 

        // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
        // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
        if($login_ok) 
        { 
            // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by 
            // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is 
            // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values 
            // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these 
            // sensitive values first. 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 

            // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'. 
            // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether 
            // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve 
            // the user's details. 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

            // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
            header("Location: index.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: index.php"); 
        } 
        else { 
            // Tell the user they failed 
            $error = "Invalid Username or Password"; 

            // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new 
            // password. The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks. You should 
            // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them 
            // to any users (including the user that submitted them). For more information: 
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: You need to explain what problems you are having with the current code, and ideally the [shortest code possible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not necessarily having any "problems" with the code. It's working fine as far as what its currently doing, I just need additional code that will pick out the database value of admin 0 or 1 and grant access to administrators only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work :-

```
if($check_password === $row['password'] && $row['admin'] == 1)
{
$login_ok = 1;
}else 
{
$login_ok = 0;
}
```

OR

You can change your query

```
$query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                admin
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username
                admin = 1
        ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that seems to decline all user and admin access.

Comment: Sorry, just one last question. Any idea on a common code to use on all admin pages to keep the standard "0" users out? I noticed that if I login on the user area, I can still access other admin pages if I type in a direct path. Essentially what it's doing now is just keeping them from going through admin the login page, and that's it. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: You can use a $_SESSION variable for that.
For e.g. $_SESSION['adminaccess'] = "yes";
and check it every time when the admin pages are accessed.